# Help understanding Feigenbaum constants from bifurcation mapping

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-mathematics, bifurcation, chaos-theory

I'm trying to understand how the author wants me to "determine the constants" for this part of *A Survey of Computational Physics Introductory Computational Science:*

[image]

The sequence of $\mu_k$ values (12.13) are

$$3, 3.449, 3.544, 3.5644, 3.5688, 3.569692, 3.56989, ...$$

My problem is conceptually understanding what they're even talking about. They point out this one series that indicates where the bifurcation diagram splits. Then they say that the series can be represented in that other form (to the right of the arrow). But do they mean this:

$$\mu_\infty - \frac{c}{\delta^k} = 3, 3.449, 3.544, 3.5644, 3.5688, 3.569692, 3.56989, ...$$

...and if so, what does that even mean??? And what is $k$??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants#/media/File:Feigenbaum.png $\leftarrow$ image that maybe makes some sense of it.

Comment: @mathreadler ok this is starting to make a bit of sense now...but then how does one determine these constants?

Comment: Ok, so that will give me $\delta$. What about $c$ and $\mu_\infty$?

Comment: Am I right about $\mu_\infty - \frac{c}{\delta^k} = 3, 3.449, 3.544, 3.5644, 3.5688, 3.569692, 3.56989, ...$? Or, what is the relationship between *all the constants* and the series? The author simply draws the arrow attempting to relate the series, but that's too vague for me to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58023/discussion-between-mathreadler-and-loltospoon).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion in the comments.

The $\mu_k$ seems to be the *least parameter* of the non-linear mapping where $k$ bifurcations has occurred (doublings of solutions that the iterate "hops" between). This is modelled as a geometric series with quotient $$\delta \approx \frac{\mu_{k}-\mu_{k-1}}{\mu_{k+1}-\mu_k}$$

How much larger span of parameters from the last bifurcation to the next.

The **Feigenbaum constant** is the $\delta \approx 4.66...$ number that is the same bifurcation gap in parameter space ( that this is the same for all second degree mappings was the remarkable thing Feigenbaum found in 78 ).

The $c$ is the distance in parameter space from first bifurcation to chaos occurs. I don't think this one is independent of which second order mapping we are testing.

So use the sequence $\{\mu_k\}$ that you can measure to estimate $\delta$, then use $\mu_\infty - \frac{c}{\delta^k}$ to estimate $c$.

You can probably derive it from wikipedia expressions of geometric series if you want to.

Comment: Hello again. I'm having some trouble understanding this. The book I am following defines $\delta$ as $\delta=\text{lim}_{k\to \infty} \frac{\mu _k - \mu_{k-1}}{\mu_{k+1} - \mu_k}$. So because $k \to \infty$, it seems as though I need to find $\mu_{\infty}$ first, correct?

Comment: That's the definition, but it is likely that it will become increasingly difficult to estimate $\mu_k$ as $k$ increases due to the exponential growth of solutions (doubling each time) and the smaller and smaller steps in parameter required for bifurcation. The intervals will divide by roughly 4.66 each time which means you will lose $>2$ bits of precision every time.